# Find Variable Declaration in Mathcad

Tags: mathcad

Is there a way to quickly find where a variable was initially defined/declared in Mathcad.

I'm working in a rather large Mathcad (150 pages get printed).  I'll see an equation that is using variables declared in earlier sections however I can't use the Edit->Find since the variable uses subscripting. I resort to eye scanning for the variable declaration.

In Eclipse you can control click on a variable and it will take you to the variables declaration.  Is there something similar in Mathcad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a 'search for definition' feature.  I believe that there have been a number of requests for it over the years ...

Why can't you Edit/Find, though?  Which kind of subscripting are you referring to: index or name? Which version of Mathcad are you using?

Search for an array name shouldn't be a problem, as the index won't form part of the name.

If you want a subscripted name and you are using Mathcad 15 (or lower), then simply type the name as you would enter it; eg if your variable is x<sub>sub</sub> then type x.sub in the find box.

Comment: No problem.  After a bit of playing around, I found that in Prime you type the name without the '.', so in the example above typing xsub in the Find box will find any instances of x<sub>sub</sub> as well as plain xsub.